# I am not able to get the full data using BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this [website](http://www.zooplus.co.uk/shop/dogs/dry_dog_food/royal_canin_vet_diet) for simple learning and I am just trying to print all the products in that website using `find_all()` command. There are total twelve product with tag `tbody` and class `product-variant-list`. But I am getting only five and I am not able to find what is the problem here.

My Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.zooplus.co.uk/shop/dogs/dry_dog_food/royal_canin_vet_diet'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")

product_list = soup.find_all("tbody", {"class":"product-variants-list"})

i=0

for product in product_list:

    product_name = product.find("a",{"class":"follow3"}).find("b").text
    print i, product_name
    #product_variants = product.find_all("tr",{"class":"product-variant"})
    i +=1
```

The html is:

```html
<table id="product-list" width="658" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" border="0">

    <tbody class="products-header"></tbody>
    <tbody class="product-variants-list">
        <tr></tr>
        <tr class="text" style="background-color:#ffffff;">
            <td valign="middle" colspan="6">
                <a class="follow3" title="Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Hypoallergenic DR 21" href="/shop/dogs/dry_dog_food/royal_canin_vet_diet/307309">
                    <b>

                        Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Hypoallergenic DR 21

                    </b>
                    ::after
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="text" style="background-color:#ffffff;"></tr>
        <tr class="text product-variant"></tr>
        <tr class="text product-variant"></tr>
        <tr class="text product-variant"></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="product-adzone"></tbody>
    <tbody class="product-variants-list"></tbody>
    <tbody class="product-adzone"></tbody>
    <tbody class="product-variants-list"></tbody>
    <tbody class="product-adzone"></tbody>
    <tbody class="product-variants-list"></tbody>
    <tbody class="product-adzone"></tbody>
    <tbody class="product-variants-list"></tbody>
    <tbody class="product-adzone"></tbody>
    <tbody class="product-variants-list"></tbody>
    <tbody class="product-adzone"></tbody>
    <tbody class="product-variants-list"></tbody>
    <tbody class="product-adzone"></tbody>
    <tbody class="product-variants-list"></tbody>
    <tbody class="product-adzone"></tbody>
    <tbody class="product-variants-list"></tbody>
    <tbody class="product-adzone"></tbody>
    <tbody class="product-variants-list"></tbody>
    <tbody class="product-adzone"></tbody>
    <tbody class="product-variants-list"></tbody>
    <tbody class="product-adzone"></tbody>
    <tbody class="product-variants-list"></tbody>
    <tbody class="product-adzone"></tbody>
    <tbody class="products-footer"></tbody>

</table>
```

My Output:

```
0 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Hypoallergenic DR 21
1 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Sensitivity Control SC 21
2 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Gastro Intestinal GI 25
3 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Renal RF 14
4 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Obesity Management DP 34
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your mistake is this line :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
```

If you change "lxml" with "html.parser" it will work.

This is the complete code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.zooplus.co.uk/shop/dogs/dry_dog_food/royal_canin_vet_diet'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

product_list = soup.find_all("tbody", {"class":"product-variants-list"})

i=0

for product in product_list:

    product_name = product.find("a",{"class":"follow3"}).find("b").text
    print i, product_name
#product_variants = product.find_all("tr",{"class":"product-variant"})
i +=1
```

And the result is :

```
0 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Hypoallergenic DR 21
1 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Sensitivity Control SC 21
2 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Gastro Intestinal GI 25
3 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Renal RF 14
4 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Obesity Management DP 34
5 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Urinary S/O LP 18
6 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Mobility MS 25
7 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Satiety Support SAT 30
8 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Hepatic HF 16
9 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Dental DLK 22
10 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Diabetic DS 37
11 Royal Canin Veterinary Diet - Calm CD 25
```

Hope it helps !

Have a nice day

### ** UPDATE **

Difference between lxml and html parser is well explained here :http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers

> If the document is not perfectly-formed, different parsers will give different results. Here’s a short, invalid document parsed using lxml’s HTML parser. Note that the dangling
>
> tag is simply ignored:

**Result with lxml**

```
BeautifulSoup("<a></p>", "lxml")
<html><body><a></a></body></html>
```

Here’s the same document parsed using html5lib:

**Result with html5lib**

```
BeautifulSoup("<a></p>", "html5lib")
<html><head></head><body><a><p></p></a></body></html>
```

**Result with html.parser**

```
BeautifulSoup("<a></p>", "html.parser")
<a></a>
```

Comment: can you tell me the difference